# How to handle different points sizes of different fonts?

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontspec, unicode-math, ebgaramond

I'm trying to use EBGaramond font together with TeX Gyre Pagella and Asana-Math as math font. But 12pt EBGaramond font looks somehow smaller than Pagella in text and Asana in math.
Why that's the case is discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167290/why-do-different-fonts-have-different-point-sizes). But I'm wondering if there's a solution to still use the fonts together?

Minimal working example:

```
% compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[%
    ,Extension = .otf
    ,UprightFont = *-Regular
    ,ItalicFont = *-Italic
    ,BoldFont = texgyrepagella-bold
    ,BoldItalicFont = texgyrepagella-bolditalic
]{EBGaramond12}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf}
\begin{document}
This Garamond Text \textbf{and bold Pagella}

Inline numbers like $12345$ and math $α+Δ$ are too big as well.
\end{document}
```

[image: The outcome]

For the Garamond Pagella deviation I assume that I can use the "Scale" option in the "fontspec" package.
But the math font is too big. So my question is: can I set the size of the math font seperately?

I'm aware of the option in the unicode-math package:

```
\setmathfont{Minion Math}[
SizeFeatures = {
{Size = -6.01, Font       = MinionMath-Tiny},
{Size = 6.01-8.41, Font   = MinionMath-Capt},
{Size = 8.41-13.01, Font  = MinionMath-Regular},
{Size = 13.01-19.91, Font = MinionMath-Subh},
{Size = 19.91-, Font      = MinionMath-Disp}
}]
```

But isn't there a simpler way set the math font on 11pt for example and see if that fits better to the EBGaramond12?

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113891/using-multiple-fonts-for-maths-and-text) is somehow similar but doesn't present a solution at all. Isn't there one?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Even if you're a sinner against typography! Everybody is welcome here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to be one of the ugliest documents I've ever seen. `;-)`

Mixing Palatino, a 20th century font, with EB Garamond, that tries to reproduce a 17th century font with completely different features is a typographic sin. Please, don't do it. And don't use boldface with Garamond under any circumstances.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
  Extension = .otf,
  UprightFont = *-Regular,
  ItalicFont = *-Italic,
  BoldFont = texgyrepagella-bold,
  BoldFeatures = {Scale=MatchLowercase},
  BoldItalicFont = texgyrepagella-bolditalic,
  BoldItalicFeatures = {Scale=MatchLowercase},
]{EBGaramond12}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Asana-Math.otf}
\begin{document}
This Garamond Text \textbf{and bold Pagella}

Inline numbers like $12345$ and math $α+Δ$ are too big as well.
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see from the image, the result is really ugly. Here's a quick comparison of uppercase

[image]

but the differences are even more striking with lowercase

[image]

There's no way Garamond a Palatino can live together.

Comment: Thanks! That was easy. How did I miss the "scale" option for the math package? So far I'm not using bold text and I hopefully don't need it because you're totally right.

Comment: @Paolo Are you *really* wanting to go this way? Please, don't inflict this to your readers! `;-)`

Comment: But which OTF math font fits better to the Garamond text then? The amount of math fonts that work together with the "unicode-math" package is quite humble unfortunately

Comment: Anyway since you solved my main problem about scaling the math font I'll mark this as answered. Thanks again!

Comment: @Paolo There is only a legacy math font, `ebgaramond-math`, as far as I know